# Using Zapier to process a backlog of existing emails in GMail?

Tags: zapier

I've successfully set up a Zap to process new emails matching a given search in my Gmail account (extracting info and adding it to a Google Sheet). But I'd like to make it process the 145 existing matching emails already archived in my Gmail as well. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Unfortunately, Zapier is built around doing ongoing work, not a single task. Polling is specifically designed to only process new things after the zap has been turned on. So, you'll have to cheat a bit.

For the purposes of your backlog you could set the gmail filter to look for what it's set to now, plus a label (say, `zapier-backlog`). If you do the search right now, it should be empty (and a poll on the zap with that search shouldn't return anything). **After** you turn the zap on, add that label to all emails you want processed, and the'll show up as "new" to the zap and all get processed accordingly.

Once that's done, you'll want to remove those changes and only have it process new emails. Hope this helps. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!